# What is the difference between “by” and “under” an act?

Tags: england-and-wales, legal-terms, interpretation, statutory-construction, legislative-drafting

E.g. s149(1)(a), Equality Act 2010 says:

> A public authority must, in the exercise of its functions, have due regard to the need to—

> (a)eliminate discrimination, harassment, victimisation and any other conduct that is prohibited *by or under* this Act;

Why does it specify both words, “by” and “under” when they both apparently mean the same thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"By or under" is redundant. It is a [legal doublet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legal_doublet).

The Australian Capital Territory Parliamentary Counsel's Office's  *Words and Phrases Guide* (at [B-10](https://www.pco.act.gov.au/__data/assets/pdf_file/0020/2216081/Words-and-Phrases.pdf#page=104) and at [xiii](https://www.pco.act.gov.au/__data/assets/pdf_file/0020/2216081/Words-and-Phrases.pdf#page=13)) says to "never use" "by and/or under" and to instead simply use "under."

A [drafting point at p. 30](https://unctad.org/system/files/official-document/imo99d3.pdf#page=30) of a "Compilation of comments and proposals by Governments and by intergovernmental and non-governmental organizations on the
draft articles for a convention on arrest of ships":

> The words “by or under” (the authority) seem to be redundant. It is
> suggested that the words “by or” be deleted so that the text would read:
> “ ... only under the authority ...”